# save editbox values in the custom listview

Tags: android, listview

am having a two editbox. the values enter in that has to placed in the custom listview its working fine for this...

but i want to save this values in the list view permanently.so that if the phones switches off and again run the app then the values have to be saved ..like phone contact number and name have to be saved..
here am ataching the code

```
public class Editcard extends Activity{

    EditText cardname,cardDescription ;

    MyApplication app;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editcredit);  

app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
 cardname =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cardash);

 cardDescription =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editdescription);

Button save =(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              app.carddata =cardname.getText().toString();

                System.out.println("Gotcardname"+app.carddata);

                app.descriptiondata =cardDescription.getText().toString();

                System.out.println("gotDescription"+app.descriptiondata);


             app.arryList.add(app.carddata);
             app.arryList1.add(app.descriptiondata);             

            Intent saveIntent =new Intent(Editcard.this,Newcard.class);

            startActivity(saveIntent);  

        }
    });

     }
}

public class MyApplication extends Application{

    ArrayList<String> arryList = new ArrayList<String>();  
     ArrayList<String> arryList1 = new ArrayList<String>();  

    String carddata,descriptiondata,=null;  
}

public class Newcard extends Activity {
     MyAdapter adapter;

    ListView listView;
    LayoutInflater lay;
    MyApplication app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.newcard);
app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());

TextView newcard =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.newcard);
newcard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent card = new Intent(Newcard.this,Editcreditcard.class);        
        startActivity(card);

    }
});

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cardlist);

adapter =new MyAdapter(this, app.arryList,app.arryList1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context = null;
ArrayList<String> items= null;
ArrayList<String> items1= null;


public MyAdapter(Newcard newcard, ArrayList<String> items,
        ArrayList<String> items1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.items = items;
    this.items1 = items1;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items; 

    //return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View layout = null;
    TextView produ = null;  
    TextView desc = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

        lay = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        layout = lay.inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
    } else {
        layout = convertView;
    }
    produ = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.card);
    produ.setText("" +app.arryList.get(position));

    desc= (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.descrip);
    desc.setText("" +app.arryList1.get(position));

    return layout;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use can use `SharedPreferences`, that will save your values permanently, untill they are changed(by changing values in editbox) or user reinstall (clear data) application. `Shared Preferences` works like this

```
// save string in sharedPreferences
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("some_key", string); // here string is the value you want to save
                    editor.commit();                    

// restore string in sharedPreferences 
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
string = settings.getString("some_key", "");
```

Comment: it has to saved like phone contact

Comment: you can save int, string, long, boolean.. just check it at official site ;) once you read documentation, you'll find out its easy to do. Good luck! :)

Comment: save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  public void onClick(View v) {    
     app.carddata =cardname.getText().toString();   
    
    app.descriptiondata =cardDescription.getText().toString();
     
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("some_key", app.carddata); 
                editor.commit();

Comment: SharedPreferences settings2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        app.string11 = settings.getString("some_key", ""); 
    
    app.arryList.add(app.string11);
    app.arryList1.add(app.descriptiondata);

and in MyApplication

 String carddata,descriptiondata,string11 =null;

Comment: but not storing listis empty